# Disabled button in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am having a problem with xaml ... a button I have created is not enable. here is the xaml part:

```
<Button Margin="0,2,2,2" Width="70" Content="Line" 
        Command="{x:Static local:DrawingCanvas.DrawShape}"
        CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
            AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DrawingTarget}"
        CommandParameter="Line">           
</Button>
```

Before Constructor it goes:

```
    public static RoutedCommand DrawShape = new RoutedCommand();
```

in ctor I have:

```
this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(DrawingCanvas.DrawShape, DrawShape_Executed, DrawShapeCanExecute));
```

Then I have:

```
private void DrawShapeCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = true;  **//Isn't this enough to make it enable?**
    en.Handled = true;
```

}

```
private void DrawShape_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Parameter.ToString())
    {
        case "Line":
            //some code here (incomplete yet)
            break;
    }
```

When I remove the first line (`Command="{x:Static ...}"`) in the block it gets enable again!

Comment: So the `Command` you're binding to must be returning `CanExecute=false`.  Can you post the part of your code that shows `DrawingCanvas.DrawShape`?

Comment: How is `DrawingCanvas.DrawShape` defined?

Comment: **DrawingCanvas** is a class and in this class **DrawShape** is defined as    `public static RoutedCommand DrawShape = new RoutedCommand();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure the `CanExecute` property of that command is returning true.  If it returns false, it automatically disables the control that utilizes that command.

Can execute should return a bool, I'm a little surprised that doesn't give a compile error.  Anyway try to change it to this.

```
private bool DrawShapeCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    return true; 
}
```

EDIT:

Ok since you just revealed all you want is a simple button that executes a command here's a very simple implementation copied from one of my recent projects.  First define this class somewhere.

```
public class GenericCommand : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged { add{} remove{} } 

    public Predicate<object> CanExecuteFunc{ get; set; }

    public Action<object> ExecuteFunc{ get; set; }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecuteFunc(parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ExecuteFunc(parameter);
    }
}
```

Next define a command in your view model and define both the properties I created in the generic command (it's just the basic stuff that comes along with implementing the ICommand interface).

```
 public GenericCommand MyCommand { get; set; }

 MyCommand = new GenericCommand();
 MyCommand.CanExecuteFunc = obj => true;
 MyCommand.ExecuteFunc = obj => MyMethod;

 private void MyMethod(object parameter)
 {
      //define your command here
 }
```

Then just wire up the button to your command.

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
```

If this is all too much for you (MVVM does require a little extra initial setup).  You can always just do this...

```
<Button Click="MyMethod"/>
```

```
private void MyMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //define your method
}
```

Comment: CanExecute has `e.CanExecute = true;` in it and it is the 3rd argument of CommandBinding() ... yet it is disabled.

Comment: @amitkohan from what you posted it looks like that code is never called, but it's hard to say without posting a little more of how you have things set up.  Can you post how the command itself is defined (DrawingCanvas.DrawShape)

Comment: This is all I have 1) `declaring DrawShape` as routed command 2)bindingcommand  3)setting `DrawShapeCanExecute()`  4)Finally the handler which is `DrawShape_Executed()`.    Am I missing here ?

Comment: It sounds very promising and in fact it should work but yet it is disable. These are strange things in WPF which I don't enjoy at all.

Comment: Also, I'm getting error! it seems compiler doesn't like boolean return.    it says:  System.Windows.Input.CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs)' has the wrong return type

Comment: @amitkohan could you add your RoutedCommand class 
and where it is initialized so we can see the all picture .

i.e. i want to see if adding CommandManager's Requery Suggested event is necessary , and if your RoutedCommand should be declared as a Dependency Property

Comment: @Eran all I'm doing is only and only having a button on a form. Nothing more. all the code I have is posted here and if creating a single button (only showing it such can be clicked using mouse) requires more than this then .... I have no idea

Comment: @amitkohan If that is really all you are trying to do you are doing all kinds of unnecessary things, just look up basic command structure, or if you don't particularly care about MVVM, just use a regular click event.